# How to fetch previous status of an issue in JIRA using Python-Jira?

Tags: python, jira, python-jira

I want to fetch all the issues which are currently in 'IN PROGRESS' status and previously in 'OPEN'status.

By using the following code I would get all the issues that are currently in 'IN PROGRESS' status and the issues that are passed through 'OPEN' status once in its transition state.

eg: **issues = jira.search_issues(PROJECT=XYZ AND (status in ('IN PROGRESS')) AND (status WAS in ('OPEN')))**

But how can I get the issues which are currently in the 'IN PROGRESS' status and previously in 'OPEN' status in JIRA using Jira-Python?

Comment: looks like some of the discussion in this [link](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Jira-questions/How-to-get-issue-history-with-JIRA-API/qaq-p/1290968) should help (if go down in discussion can even see others using python jira package)

Comment: @kamster Thanks. I have already gone through the discussion a few days ago and got a solution using the Changelog. But in the above method, I have to traverse through each issue and fetch the previous status which is a bit time-consuming process. If there is a keyword or something available in JQL(Jira Query Language), it would be really helpful.

Comment: from what i know of JIRA queries and such i dotn think that is possible. reason being JIRA queries are just querying on the current status/view of JIRA (not meant to look through history)

Comment: I believe you would have to instead have custom field that stores the previous status. now dont know exact means on how would auto trigger that but seems discussion in [link](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Jira-questions/Automation-for-Jira-Transition-to-previous-state/qaq-p/837709) could likely help

Answer (score 0):

You can run a search using Jira Python. Use the same search you showed us